# Hibernate not found table in schema

Tags: spring, hibernate, reactive, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a bit a problem, I have several microservices, but one throws an exception that others don't throws and work perfect ...

```
[2020-09-28 16:55:38.304]|ERROR|TIBCO EMS Session Dispatcher (21297)|org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions^[[36m(142)^[[0;39m: --- ERROR: relation "computed.fluxeventlogging" does not exist
  Position: 502
[2020-09-28 16:55:38.307]|INFO |TIBCO EMS Session Dispatcher (21297)|org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad^[[36m(116)^[[0;39m: --- HHH000327: Error performing load command
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

I have good permissions in a database like that:

[image]

And my entity is located in a common projet used by all microservice, added with maven dependency.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="fluxeventlogging", schema = "computed")
@IdClass(FluxEventLoggingIdEntity.class)
public class FluxEventLoggingEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "fluxeventuuid", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID   fluxEventUuid;
    @Column(name = "lastupdatedate")
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;
    @Column(name = "businessfluxtype")
    private String businessFluxType;
    @Column(name = "fluxprocessortype")
    private String fluxProcessorType;
    @Column(name = "valuewhichcauseupdate")
    private String valueWhichCauseUpdate;
    @Column(name = "oldvaluecause")
    private String oldValueCause;
    @Column(name = "newvaluecause")
    private String newValueCause;
    @Column(name = "currenteventlifestate")
    private String currentEventLifeState;
    @Column(name = "nexteventlifestate")
    private String nextEventLifeState;
    @Column(name = "generatederror", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String generatedError;
}
```

however I fixed in pom the hibernate version to:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

because this project is the only once which use one data source for jpa like that:

```
custom.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
custom.datasource.database: postgres
custom.datasource.driver: pool
custom.datasource.protocol: postgres
custom.datasource.localhost: localhost
custom.datasource.port: 5432
custom.datasource.password: postgres
custom.datasource.username: postgres
custom.datasource.driverclassname: org.postgresql.Driver

    spring:
      jpa:
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: create
        show-sql: false
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        schema: classpath:/schema.sql
        initialization-mode: always
      r2dbc:
        url: r2dbc:postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
        pool:
          enabled: true
          initial-size=: 00
          max-size: 500
          max-idle-time: 30m
          validation-query: SELECT 1
```

And another data source for r2dbc (postgres reactive)

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private static Map<String, Object> PROPERTIES;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory r2dbcConnectionFactory() {
        if(PROPERTIES == null) {
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                    .getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("application.yml");
            PROPERTIES = yaml.load(inputStream);
        }
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with host: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.localhost").toString());
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with port: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.port").toString());
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with database: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.database").toString());
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with username: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.username").toString());
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with driver: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.driver").toString());
        log.info("Init rd2dbc with protocol: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.protocol").toString());
    ConnectionFactoryOptions options = ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.DRIVER, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.driver").toString())
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PROTOCOL, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.protocol").toString())
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.username").toString())
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.password").toString())
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.HOST, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.localhost").toString())
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PORT, Integer.parseInt(PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.port").toString()))
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.DATABASE, PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.database").toString())
            .build();
        return ConnectionFactories.get(options);
        //return ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.parse(PROPERTIES.get("custom.r2dbc.url").toString()));
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        if(PROPERTIES == null) {
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                    .getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("application.yml");
            PROPERTIES = yaml.load(inputStream);
        }
        log.info("Init datasource with url: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.url").toString());
        log.info("Init datasource with username: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.username").toString());
        log.info("Init datasource with driver: {}", PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.driverclassname").toString());
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.url").toString());
        dataSourceBuilder.username(PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.username").toString());
        dataSourceBuilder.password(PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.password").toString());
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(PROPERTIES.get("custom.datasource.driverclassname").toString());
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        //JpaVendorAdapteradapter can be autowired as well if it's configured in application properties.
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        //Add package to scan for entities.
        factory.setPackagesToScan("fr.microservice2.database", "fr.microservice.common");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
```

I don't know why only this microservice don't found my table `computed.fluxeventlogging` ...
while I have plenty of other tables in this diagram where it does not bring up the problem

Anyone have an idea please?
Thank you and best regards

Comment: Are you sure if you are using correct JDBC driver ?

Comment: How I can check it ?

Comment: As you use **PostgreSQL 8.2** (`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect`) you can use the latest version of jdbc [driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html). Could you please also provide the table DDL if driver update will not help.

Comment: @AdrienRuffie First, you need to find the correct version of your Postgres server.

Comment: @AdrienRuffie did you solve this issue?